# A form has 7 questions, each with 3 possible answers: A , B , or C. How many ways that the answer sheet has the same number of A and B

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I'm thinking about there are 4 cases:

1. All C, No A or B.
2. Exactly 1 A and 1 B.
3. Exactly 2 A and 2 B.
4. Exactly 3 A and 3 B.

However, I don't know to calculate the 2, 3, and 4 case.

Comment: For number 2, how many ways can you get one $A$? Given that one answer is an $A$, how many ways are there to get a $B$?

Comment: @JohnDouma 1 question can be A and 1 can be B while the rest are all C. However, the order can be vary from the 1st question to the 7th. I don't know how to calculate all the possibilities